# How to use the getx middleware effectively?

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, sharedpreferences, middleware

I'm having an infinite loop whenever I use the middleware provided by `GetX`. So here is my setup, first here is my main file, I'm initiliazing a shared preferences object:

```dart
SharedPreferences? prefs;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(const EpidemicZone());
}
```

In the `EpidemicZone()` I have this setup:

```dart
class EpidemicZone extends StatelessWidget {
  const EpidemicZone({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialBinding: AppBindings(),
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: '/',
          page: () => const HomePage(),
          middlewares: [AuthMiddleWare()],
          binding: AppBindings(),
        ),
        GetPage(
          name: '/app',
          page: () => const AppPage(),
          middlewares: [AuthMiddleWare()],
          binding: AppBindings(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The `AuthMiddleWare` that I created is this:

```dart
class AuthMiddleWare extends GetMiddleware {
  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    print('Redirect middleware executed for route: $route');

    if (prefs!.getInt('id') != null) {
      print('User ID found in SharedPreferences. Redirecting to /app');

      return const RouteSettings(name: '/app');
    } else {
      print('User ID not found in SharedPreferences. Redirecting to /');

      return const RouteSettings(name: '/');
    }
  }
}
```

I added the two prints to debug and try to find the solution but the problem is I'm getting an infinite loop of the two messages:

> I/flutter (26075): User ID not found in SharedPreferences. Redirecting to /

> I/flutter (26075): Redirect middleware executed for route: /

> I/flutter (26075): User ID not found in SharedPreferences. Redirecting to /

> I/flutter (26075): Redirect middleware executed for route: /

> I/flutter (26075): User ID not found in SharedPreferences. Redirecting to /

> I/flutter (26075): Redirect middleware executed for route: /

> I/flutter (26075): User ID not found in SharedPreferences. Redirecting to /
> 1086

> [GETX] Redirect to RouteSettings("/", null)

> I/flutter (26075): Redirect middleware executed for route: /

And it's an inifinite loop. For further more information, I have a controller named `AppPageController` that wraps the app page like this:

```dart
class AppPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<AppPageController>(
      builder: (controller) => Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: IndexedStack(
            index: controller.currentIndex,
            children: [
              MapPage(),
              RecommendationsPage(),
              ProfilePage2(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: controller.currentIndex,
          onTap: controller.changePage,
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.article),
              label: 'Recommendations',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I defined an `onInit()` method so that I create a `User` instance whenever the user logs in. Here is my `AppPageController`:

```dart
final UserController userController = Get.find<UserController>();

class AppPageController extends GetxController {
  var currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    await userController.createUserUsingId();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void changePage(int index) {
    currentIndex = index;
    if (currentIndex == 1) {
      final RecommandationController recommandationController =
          Get.find<RecommandationController>();

      recommandationController.getRecommandations();
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

And finally here is my `UserController` :

```dart
class UserController extends GetxController {
  User? _user;

  User? get user => _user;

  void setUser(User user) {
    if (_user != user) {
      _user = user;
      update();
    }
  }

  void rebuild() {
    update();
  }

  Future<void> createUserUsingId() async {
    int userId = prefs!.getInt('id')!;

    User user = await DjangoHelper.getUserById(userId);

    setUser(user);
  }

  void clear(User? user) {
    if (_user == user) {
      _user = null;
      user = null;
      update();
    }
  }
}
```

By the way the `DjangoHelper.getUserById(userId)` is just creating a user with the provided user id, and I'm sure that It's working perfectly.

Comment: I cannot switch to another state management in the current moment @RandalSchwartz